# insert after an element jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

From jquery how to insert o

```
   <tr><td>some other data</td></tr>
```

after the tr id=user

```
<table>
<tr id="user">
 <td>some data</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this...Use the [jQuery after() method](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
$("#user").after("<tr><td>some other data</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table').append('<tr><td>some other data</td></tr>')
```

`.append` will place the html at right before the end tag of the selector.

Comment: ..Using the table selector and the append may not guarantee that the html appended is immediately after the tr with id=user, if there are more rows in the table.

Comment: @John true. Though for the given example, both our solutions will work. I was thinking ahead to his wanting to sequentially add rows to that table and not just as a one-off problem.