# Inserting a element with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an application that uses a series of functions to render and populate form fields. I need to insert an arbitrary div underneath one of the form fields, but I'd rather not make any changes to the form code. Is there a way that I can just insert the field where I want it with Jquery? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155521/insert-after-an-element-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
$("<div>..</div>").insertAfter("#form-id")
```

Comment: Actually... `$("#form-id").after("<div>..</div>");` is prettier

Comment: I would prefer `$("#form-id").after("<div>..</div>");` over the one you posted because it helps to continue the `$(selector).action();` format used by most jQuery. Its the pattern more commonly used, but its more or less user preference.

Comment: Ok, I thought about the same thing :).

Comment: @Chad, it's more than user preference. In this case `after` returns the `form` and `insertAfter` returns the `div`, depending on which (if any) will need another method chained to it will influence the decision on which to use.

Comment: @StuperUser However, in this case there is no return value being used so it is user preference.

Comment: Very true in this case, but worth making the point since OP or future readers may not be fully aware of the way chaining works. Last year I would've written a new selector after adding it in.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input#whichInput').after($('<div/>'));
```

Inserts a div after the selected input.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `after` function:

```
var $div = $("<div/>");
// (construct the content of your div)
$("#the_field").after($div);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the DOM insertion sections in the documentation (see the tree on the left hand side of the page) http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/.

You can select an element and insert your div before it, inside it (at the start or end) or after it, depending on your needs.

Also, in this case:
`.after` returns the `form`
`.insertAfter` returns the `div`

Depending on whether the `form` or `div` needs another method chained to it will influence the decision on which to use.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
<div id="d">
</div>


$('#d').append('child');

<div id="d">
    child
</div>



$('<div>child</div>').appendTo('#d');
<div id="d">
    <div>child</div>
</div>


$('#d').after('<b>after</b>');
<div id="d">
</div><b>after</b>
```